# Unable to JOIN tables when replacing string as Id to join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data as follows:

```
[Main].[Relation]
'SalesMan1'
'Supplier1'
'Customer2'
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Main] [M]
INNER JOIN [SalesMan] [S]
ON [S].[Id] = Replace([M].[Relation],'SalesMan','')
WHERE [M].[Relation] LIKE 'SalesMan%'


Getting exeception :
**Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Supplier1' to data type int.**
```

I am unable to JOIN tables when replacing string as Id to join. Any ideas on how resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `=` use `LIKE`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [Main] [M] INNER JOIN 
       [SalesMan] [S] ON [S].[Id] = CAST(REPLACE([M].[Relation],'SalesMan','') AS INT)
WHERE  [M].[Relation] LIKE 'SalesMan%'
```